# Links in new menu don't work

Tags: menus, jquery, admin, navigation, links

My links in navigation don't work if they're not exactly some menu from Admin Panel. Why?

On my website http://pstrykamy.pl everything is working.
I created a new page and a new template page - http://pstrykamy.pl/new-page .

In template page I changed:

```
'theme_location' => 'main_nav'
```

to:

```
'theme_location' => 'outpage_nav'
```

and added this menu in functions.php

Everything is ok for now.

So now I assign new menu in wordpress admin panel to this outpage_nav. Menu is visible properly but we can't click on any link.

The same bug is with every other menu I have in Admin Panel - footer menu etc. Only fully working menu is original main menu visible on homepage which I've got from developer who did the original template.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a script active that prevents normal behaviour of links if they have no `target="_blank"` attribute on them. The original site has this attribute on the link to the blog, so that one works. The 'new' site doesn't have it on the menu links, so those links are disabled.

To fix this, go to the menu section in admin. In your screen option, make sure that you can edit the target on links. Change accordingly.

Note that this means every page of your site will be opened in a new window, which is not very user friendly. Changing the script would be better.